# Making Angular 2 ignore html5 validation

Tags: validation, angular

This is a general question but I'll try to explain with an example:

I have a form (constructed and validated with FormBuilder) with input fields that have the pattern attribute on them in order to make safari on ios popup the numeric keyboard, like so `<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*">`

I've written custom validators for these fields, but also masking routines that format the input (e.g.`07 / 2016` for dates).

This all works great, except that Angular2 treats the form controls as invalid, even tho they pass my own validation. This is due to the spaces and slashes, as they make the html5 validation fail, because of the pattern attribite.

So how can I make Angular completely ignore html5 validation and only care about my own validators?

Edit: I've tried adding the `novalidate` attribute to the form, but it has no effect on this.

Comment: Did you already try to add the novalidate attribute to the form tag? Like <form novalidate></form>

Comment: I just edited before I saw your reply. Unfortunately, the novalidate attribute on the form seems to have no effect.

Comment: @DanielC any update on this. Did you get the issue resolved?

Comment: @Programmer Unfortunately, no. Tho I haven't tried the more recent versions of Angular, I'm still interested in a solution since I bet this issue will arise in future projects as well.